# parse out the number value in a string using vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net, split

I have two different strings.

```
               www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/myncbi/browse/collection/40918026/?sort=date&direction=descending
```

and

```
              https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sites/myncbi/john.smith.1/bibliography/47926757/public/?sort=date&direction=descending
```

I need the number that is in the block after the word collection or bibliography.  I know that I can split the "/" slashes but if it starts with http then it will not be the same.  Plus one would be in position 5 and the other in 6.  Is there a better way using regex?  I know I can put together a bunch of code searching for either word and then doing something different but I'm looking for a cleaner way to pull it out

I'm using

```
              Dim str() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split("/")

              For i As Integer = 0 To str.Length - 1
              If Regex.IsMatch(str(i), "^[0-9 ]+$") Then
              MessageBox.Show(str(i).ToString)
              End If

              Next
```

But hoped for something cleaner

Comment: `Is there a better way using regex?`, sure is and a few other ways as well. Since you are asking for a review it is better suited at [Codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). Also IMHO answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: It's not that much dirty. Anyway, here's a possible substitute: `Dim result As String = Input.Split({"/"c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(Function(s) Regex.Match(s, "^[0-9 ]+$").Value).FirstOrDefault(Function(s) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))`

Comment: I like that-  Thanks

Comment: This one is better: `Dim result As String = Input.Split({"/"c}).FirstOrDefault(Function(s) Regex.Match(s, "^[0-9 ]+$").Value <> String.Empty)`

Answer (score 2):

Try with this regex: `(?:collection|bibliography)\/(\d+)`

The desired number will be on the first *[capturing group](https://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-vbnet)*

See **[demo](https://regex101.com/r/455qzC/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for the input but I going to use Jimi's code--  Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

A similar, but simple alternative approach without splitting:

> A per your examples: (Assuming one eight digit number surrounded by
>   "/")

```
Dim Result As String = Regex.Match(TextBox1.Text, "\/\d{8}\/").Value.Replace("/", String.Empty)
```

`Result` will contain your number if matched, else `String.Empty`

Reference: [Regex.Match Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=netframework-4.7.2)

**Example alternatives:**

Only match numbers with length of 8 to 10 digits enclosed in "/":  `"\/\d{8,10}\/"`

Only match numbers with length of 4 or more digits enclosed in "/":  `"\/\d{4,}\/"`

Match numbers of any length enclosed in "/":  `"\/\d+\/"`

Comment: Hmm, `d{8}`? How do you know?

Comment: Actually I don't. It's just both of the OP examples had 8 numbers. There was no mention they could be different in length. Thus my answer is just obviously for 8 digits but could be amended of course depending on the possible number lengths the OP expects.

Comment: Just `"^\d+"` could do it?

Comment: Yes `"^\d+"` will work if you split. I was just giving a no split example.

Comment: Lol, I left inside a piece of the original pattern :) I was referring to, more or less, what Julio posted: `"\/\d+"`.

Comment: I know what you meant :-) The only thing that would worry me though is in the event of the URL path consisting of something like `/1/` or `/2/` etc... before the required number. I'm sure that's not the case but it's just all guess work on our part. If it's always 8 numbers I'd personally prefer the `d{8}` just to be extra sure. If the length of the numbers vary then obviously your approach would be more suitable.

Comment: It's just a suggestion. This is your answer, it's up to you to provide a solution :) Codexer suggested to post it on CodeReview for a reason. But, since you answered, maybe you could try a more flexible way. Something that the possible future views might enjoy finding. (I won't bother you further, don't worry :)

Comment: Yes you're right about Codexer's comment, it's all opinions. I edited my answer slightly to show a couple of alternatives to use. Might be helpful to someone. Oh and it's no bother, thanks for the comments.

Comment: I agree with both of you and also Codexer's comment but from a person that has been coding for nearly 35 years your comments and opinions are extremely important and are deeply appreciated.  Most of the time there is never 1 solution and opinions and different styles do matter